# I have a model class, using which I save to realm. How do I use `contains()` to see if the object has already been stored

Tags: java, android, realm

Here's the model class -

```
public class BasicSavedInfoImpl extends RealmObject implements BasicSavedInfo {

    private String iD;

    @Override
    public String getID() {
        return iD;
    }

    @Override
    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.iD= ID;
    }


}
```

Here's how I write `id` to realm -

```
realm.beginTransaction();
        BasicSavedInfoImpl basicSavedInfoImpl = realm.createObject(BasicSavedInfoImpl.class);
        basicSavedInfoImpl.setID(id);
        realm.commitTransaction();
```

How do I check to see it realm already contains the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you want to use contains? The below would be more precise:

```
BasicSavedInfoImpl obj = realm.where(BasicSavedInfoImpl.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
if (obj != null) {
  // success
}
```

If you want to use contains the following should work

```
RealmResults<BasicSavedInfoImpl> objs = realm.where(BasicSavedInfoImpl.class).contains("id", id).findAll();
if (objs.size() > 0) {
  // success
}
```

But contains will probably match ID's you don't want, ie. `contains("id", "a")` would also match ID's `"ab", "abc", "ba"` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, that was precisely what I was looking for. Can you also please provide me with an example of how to use contains to perform the same task? Just curious.

Comment: I added a contains example as well